# NoReverseMatch at / 'celery_progress' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I'm trying to integrate [this](https://github.com/czue/celery-progress) library into my django app on heroku.

It's giving me this error:

```
   NoReverseMatch at /

   'celery_progress' is not a registered namespace
```

Index.html(where the error occurs):

```
    // vanilla JS version
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var progressUrl = "{% url 'celery_progress:task_status' task_id %}";
    CeleryProgressBar.initProgressBar(progressUrl);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Registering URL with namespace will solve this issue.

```
re_path(r'^celery-progress/', include('celery_progress.urls', namespace="celery_progress")),
```